# CakePHP Shell issue

Tags: cakephp

I am just getting started with Cakephp shell and running into issues.
My cake core library is under path d:/libs/cake 
My app is setup under d:/servers/htdocs/myapp

I wrote a test shell under d:/servers/htdocs/myapp/vendor/shells

---

```
class ReportShell extends Shell {
 var $uses = array('Appt');
 function main() {
  echo $this->Appt->find('first');


 }
}
```

---

When I try to run this code from d:/servers/htdocs/myapp , It gives me an error

---

Warning: include_once(d:/servers/htdocs/myapp/config/database.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in d:/libs/cake\libs\mode
l\connection_manager.php on line 23

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'd:/servers/htdocs/myapp/config/database.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;D:\work\xampp\php\PEAR') in d:/libs/cake\libs\model\connection_manager.php on line 23

Fatal error: ConnectionManager::getDataSource - Non-existent data source default in d:/libs/cake\libs\model\connection_manager.php on line 102

---

Reason is that it is trying to find database.php under 'd:/servers/htdocs/myapp/config/' and the correct path is 'd:/servers/htdocs/myapp/app/config/database.php'

What am I doing wrong here?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

> My app is setup under d:/servers/htdocs/myapp

No, the application directory (holding the `config` folder) is `D:\servers\htdocs\myapp\app\`.

> Reason is that it is trying to find database.php under 'd:/servers/htdocs/myapp/config/' and the correct path is 'd:/servers/htdocs/myapp/app/config/database.php'

You are in the wrong directory, therefore it can't find your database config.

> I wrote a test shell under d:/servers/htdocs/myapp/vendor/shells

Move your shell out of the global vendors folder at `D:\servers\htdocs\myapp\vendors\shells` to the application's vendors folder at `D:\servers\htdocs\myapp\app\vendors\shells` instead and try again.

(Note: I'm not actually sure where the global vendors folder should be when you have a setup where the cake and application directories are split from each other, but you definitely have to be in your application directory when running commands and not the `myapp` directory you're using.)

---

If you add `D:\libs\cake\console\` to your [PATH environment variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) (remembering to close all `cmd.exe` processes afterwards) then you will simply be able to execute the following:

`D:\servers\htdocs\myapp\app> cake report` (from within the application directory)

Otherwise you will need to type the full relative or absolute path to the cake console executable and/or provide CakePHP with the absolute path to the application directory (if you are not in it):

`D:\servers\htdocs\myapp\app> ..\..\..\..\libs\cake\console\cake report`

`D:\servers\htdocs\myapp\app> \libs\cake\console\cake report`

`D:\libs\cake\console> cake -app D:\servers\htdocs\myapp\app report`

`D:\> libs\cake\console\cake -app D:\servers\htdocs\myapp\app report`

etc...

Hopefully you can see why just adding the correct folder to your `PATH` makes things a lot easier. :)

Comment: Thanks. Here was the issue
My shell script was under /myapp/vendor/shells which was wrong. It should have been under  /myapp/app/vendor/shells. After I moved the file, it worked. Thank  you.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run it from within the `/app` directory or with the `-app` parameter specified:

```
cake -app d:/servers/htdocs/myapp/app report
```

Comment: I did but get this error:
Error: Class ReportShell could not be loaded

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. Here was the issue
 My shell script was under /myapp/vendor/shells which was wrong. It should have been under /myapp/app/vendor/shells. After I moved the file, it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

- You should always be in your APP path to execute the cake console.
- Your Shell File Should be in ..app/Console/Command/
- If your file name is TestShell.php type command app>  cake test